# How can I show that someone is part of a shift that they supervise?

Tags: mysql

I'm working with a database for a project at work where I'm looking at my employees activity.  I have the main table employees which has the employee information including the supervisor id for each employee.  I have another table that has the shifts and supervisor id.  My problem comes when I try to populate the shift information.  It populates for the employees but is null for the supervisors as they have their own supervisors.  I'm trying to figure out how to code it so that I can show that the supervisors of the shifts are part of that shift.

The base query that populates the shift information is below.

```
SELECT 
    nbr,
    Event_Activity,
    Minutes,
    hours,
    Call_for_Service,
    incident,
    LAST_NAME,
    FIRST_NAME,
    c.Employee_Nbr,
    Supervisor,
    sector_shift
FROM
    cad c
       JOIN
    employees e ON e.en = c.employee_nbr
       left JOIN
    sector s ON s.supervisor_id = e.supervisor
     order by sector_shift asc;
```

I'm very new to SQL so I appreciate any help I can get.

```
Sector
Field,         Type,        Null, Key
sector_shift,  varchar(12), NO,   PRI
supervisor_id, varchar(12), YES,  MUL

Employees 
Field           Type,          Null,  Key
Position,       varchar(255),  NO 
Job_Code,       varchar(5),    YES 
Last_Name,      varchar(25),   YES 
First_Name,     varchar(12),   YES 
Email_Address,  varchar(45),   NO,     UNI 
EN,             varchar(12),   NO,     PRI 
Hire_Date,      varchar(12),   YES
Status,         varchar(45),   YES 
Classification, varchar(12),   YES 
Supervisor,     varchar(12),   YES,    MUL 

CAD
Field,            Type,        Null,   Key
cad_id,           int(11),     NO,     PRI
Nbr,              int(11),     NO 
Event_Activity,   varchar(45), YES
Minutes,          int(11),     NO,     MUL
Hours,            varchar(25), YES
Call_for_Service, int(11),     NO,     MUL 
Incident,         int(11),     NO,     MUL 
Misd.,            int(11),     NO,     MUL 
Felony,           int(11),     NO,     MUL 
Other,            int(11),     NO,     MUL 
Report_Issued,    int(11),     NO,     MUL 
Employee_Nbr,     varchar(12), YES,    MUL
```

Here's an example of what is returned.

```
Report_Nbr,  crime,             date,     location,             LAST_NAME,   FIRST_NAME, Employee_Nbr, Supervisor, sector_shift
160002,      PROPERTY,          01/01/16, 1516 N. MAIN ST.,     HOLLIS,      NANCY,      80951,        48784,      2
160001,      PROPERTY,          01/01/16, 6592 BELLCOURT PKY,   WINCE,       TIFFANY,    48714,        57080,      3
160003,      DRUG - MARIJUANA,  01/01/16, 986 N. FRANKLIN ST.,  GARCIA,      MARK,       72420,        12133,      Delta
160005,      ACCIDENT,          01/03/16, 3765 CHARLES DR.,     ALLEN,       MICHAEL,    83701,        41647,      Alpha
160013,      DISPATCH,          01/04/16, 567 COWART LN.,       TALOBORT,    ROGER,      41647,        55054,      NULL
160007,      PROPERTY,          01/04/16, 6594 HENDERSON AVE.,  SMITH,       FRANK,      62500,        41647,      Alpha
```

The null is a supervisor so his supervisor field is pointing towards his supervisor.  What I'm trying to do is get it to show that he is on the shift he supervises.

Comment: Could you provide the schema structure ?

Comment: @berty Do the edits above help?  Employee_nbr in CAD is a foreign key that references EN in Employees and Supervisor in Employees is a foreign key referencing supervisor_id in Sector.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing what's in your schema, but if it is the case that supervisors have NULL in their supervisor_id column of the Supervisor column, then you need to make this join:

```
left JOIN
sector s ON s.supervisor_id = e.supervisor
```

a RIGHT JOIN. You may want to do some practice with LEFT, RIGHT, and INNER joins.

It also may be that you can get what you want using a union and superselect. Imagine I have a database that (unwisely, I would argue) stores employee shift data and supervisor shift data in separate tables. Their schemas differ as well:

Table employee_shifts has fields id, employee_id, full_name, shift_date, hours_worked, and supervisor_id.
Table supervisor_shifts has fields id, supervisor_id, full_name, shift_date.

Again, this would be a very unwise database schema design, but it will help understand the concept of union and superselect. Here's a query that would help me get a unified view of both tables:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM (
    SELECT 
      employee_id,
      full_name,
      shift_date,
      hours_worked,
      supervisor_id
    FROM employee_shifts
),
(
    SELECT 
      supervisor_id AS employee_id,
      full_name,
      shift_date,
      8 AS hours_worked,
      supervisor_id
    FROM supervisor_shifts
)
```

In the above example, you're using two different select statements (indented in parenthesis) unioned together with a comma. The SQL keyword AS aliases a field to be called a different name. In this case, since our schemas differ, we have to mangle the supervisor_shifts table to look more like the employee table. We do this by assuming the supervisors worked 8 hours ("8 AS hours_worked") and using their own id as employee_id.

This should help get you stared. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the schema above as well as an example of the return from my query.  the left join is correct for what I'm trying to do as I need all of the rows from the CAD table.  If I do a right join I lose about 250 rows I need.  Hopefully I've provided some more useful information above.  Please forgive me if I've messed something up I'm still very new at this but eager to learn more and better myself.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error I ended up finding that using CASE was the easiest option.  In place of sector_shift in the query I placed the following and it filled my nulls.  If anyone knows a simpler way that I could have achieved this please let me know.

```
case 
when Employee_Nbr = '38419' then '1'
when Employee_Nbr = '48784' then '2'
when Employee_Nbr = '57080' then '3'
when Employee_Nbr = '60055' then '4'  
when Employee_Nbr = '55104' then '5'
when Employee_Nbr = '59743' then '6'
when Employee_Nbr = '41647' then 'Alpha'
when employee_nbr = '52790' then 'Bravo'
when Employee_Nbr = '61462' then 'Charlie'
when employee_nbr = '12133' then 'Delta'
when employee_nbr = '56965' then 'Admin'
when sector_shift is null then 'Training'
else sector_shift
end as Sector_shift
```